# Dynamics AX connector 2012 dynamic company configuration property Mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft

I am using AX connector to call AIF service of AX 2012. The values we put in configuration property of connector like company , language etc. become header of the XML request. I need to set the company name depending upon the payload value.

How can we do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression. In Mule expressions are sorrounded by `#[ ... ]`.

I don't have a complete example but it would be similar to this:

```
<microsoft-dynamics-ax:dynamics-ax-config
        ...
        company="#[payload.clientId]"
        ...
```

Comment: From the documentation I found this -  
**Sets the company to use within all calls (this setting can be overridden using the 'dynamicsax.callcontext.company' outbound property)**. But do not know how to do it ?

Comment: outbound properties are a Mule 3 concept. Mule 4 doesn't has them. Those instructions are valid for Mule 3 only.

Comment: Hi Aled, Thanks for the response. I tried your solution but it did not worked.

Comment: It did not gave any error but it did not took the value passed on to it. `<microsoft-dynamics-ax:dynamics-ax-config name="Microsoft_Dynamics_AX_Config" doc:name="Microsoft Dynamics AX Config">
  <microsoft-dynamics-ax:gateway-connection username="${dynamicsax.gws.user}" password="${dynamicsax.gws.pass}" aosServerName="${dynamicsax.aos.host}" aosWsdlPort="${dynamicsax.aos.port.wsdl}" disableCnCheck="true" gatewayRouterServiceAddress="${dynamicsax.gws.address}" aosEndpointPort="${dynamicsax.aos.port.endpoint}" company="#[payload.legalEntity]"/></microsoft-dynamics-ax:dynamics-ax-config>`